# Lag on simultaneous jQuery UI effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, lag

On my page I run a show and hide effect with slide simultaneously on different divs, but the animation lags a bit. If I run the show effect after the hide is done it doesn't lag at all, so I'm wondering if there's any way to make this lag go away.

Code without lag:

```
$(currentPageID).stop().hide("slide", {"direction": "left"}, 1000, function(){
    $(pageID).show("slide", {"direction": "right"}, 1000);
});
```

Code with lag:

```
$(currentPageID).hide("slide", {"direction": "left"}, 1000);
$(pageID).show("slide", {"direction": "right"}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be lag so much as it is just an optical illusion based on your screen resolution, vs duration of animation vs how far it has to animate over the course of that duration. This is also in part due to the calculations of how to break down that duration to actual distance.  If you animate across 1000px in one second, and you animate across 100px in one second using the same exact code, you will notice one is more choppy than the other as the chunks of distance vs duration are different.

Again though resolution, refresh rates, and all else come into play as well. As does anything else you may have going on at the time

The difference between the two code examples you provided is that one runs the direction right upon completing direction left waiting its turn. The other the way the code reads through goes one to the other with little to no pause other than processing it.

Comment: Yea, I know what the difference is. Traveling loads of pixels in a short time may indeed seem laggy sometimes, but it's not the case here. Because the first code runs smoothly, and the second doesn't. In the first code the animations happen after each other, in the second they happen simultaneously. Since that's the only difference and it doesn't lag in the first example it must be lag...

Comment: Could also be a result of the browser(s) suffering from the equivalent of a memory leak. Calling animate on one hand seems like a single function, but the background process is many functions crunching numbers and preforming actions based on those numbers to create the animated effect, and in that, the browser(s) are just having a bit of trouble when you have multiples running simultaneously off of 2 different starting points, if that makes sense.

Comment: I'd say if you have a means of seeing how much memory the browser is using try both methods again and watch what the browser jumps up to for usage based on either. Example Windows Task Manager will let you see the memory usage of a given application, Im sure theres better 3rd party apps I just don't know any off hand

Comment: Even if that's the case, would there be a way to do this without the lag?